# How can I handle a Crystal Report's Record Selection Formula appearing as a concatenated string when loaded in C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have several Crystal Reports with Record Selection Formulas, and I'm loading them into a C# program with the help of some CrystalDecisions dll's. I have no trouble loading them or viewing their information.

However, when the reports are loaded, the multi-lined Record Selection Formulas are concatenated into a one-line string field so that it can be stored in the ReportDocument object. For regular formula fields, this is fine, as it appears to automatically include "\n" to break up the string into the multiple lines so it can make sense.

The problem seems to specifically be the Record Selection Formulas. As a simple example, here's a sample record selection formula I'd try to work with, and the result I get within C#:

**Within Crystal Reports:**

```
if (condition) then true
else false
```

**Within C#:**

```
if (condition) then trueelse false
```

If I try to use this formula, it gives the error:

`A number, currency amount, boolean, date, time, date-time, or string is expected here.`

Because obviously "trueelse" isn't valid syntax.

One thing I've tried is to change the formula in crystal to all be on one line with spaces in between rather than newlines, which does seem to work, however I have many reports so I'd like to avoid this if there's another way to fix this.

The other thing I've tried is to ensure each line has extra whitespace at the end to help break up the lines when it gets loaded, but these seem to just get trimmed.

Comment: Have you looked at the content of the variable once it's read into C#  Are there any /n or /r characters that can be replaced with either a space or Environment.Newline?

Comment: @Tintow I've set breakpoints after loading it in C# to see the contents. It doesn't have any /n or /r characters at all, even though similar formulas in the formula fields (not Record Selection Formula, which is stored in a separate field of the Report object in C#) does include them.